# Is there any command by which I can keep the spacing in my attachment

Tags: unix, sunos

I am using mailx command in my script. It is deleting all the spacing in the file and even on the attachment. 
Could you please help me in getting the desired output i.e. with the space after each line as it is in the input file.

{ echo -e "Todays Report"; uuencode "abc.txt" "abc.txt"; } | mailx -s "$header" my@gmail.com

Please guide.
Thank You

Comment: Does the version of mailx you use support MIME attachments (e.g: `-a <file>` in Heirloom mailx)?

Comment: No, if am giving -a attachment-name . its giving an error  i.e. mailx: illegal option -- a Usage: mailx -eiIUdFntBNHvV~ -T FILE -u USER -h hops -r address -s SUBJECT -f FILE users. I am using - mailx version 5.0